# VirtualProtect - AV : Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, delphi, delphi-6

I have Delphi 6 DLL which internally uses a third party library to do the automatic resource string translation.

In the library source code 2 RTL functions (`ShortCutToText` and `LoadResString`) are replaced with the multilingual counterparts (`trShortCutToText` and `trLoadResString`). Code is shown below:

```
VirtualProtect(@ShortCutToText, SIZE_C, PAGE_READWRITE, @protectType);
Move((@ShortCutToText)^, shortCutBuffer, SIZE_C);
Move((@trShortCutToText)^, (@ShortCutToText)^, SIZE_C);
VirtualProtect(@ShortCutToText, SIZE_C, protectType, @protectType);
FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess, @ShortCutToText, SIZE_C);
```

and

```
VirtualProtect(@LoadResString, SIZE_C, PAGE_READWRITE, @protectType);
Move((@LoadResString)^, loadResStringBuffer, SIZE_C);
Move((@trLoadResString)^, (@LoadResString)^, SIZE_C);
VirtualProtect(@LoadResString, SIZE_C, protectType, @protectType); //<--Exception thrown at this line
FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess, @LoadResString, SIZE_C);
```

Now when I call functions of this DLL from within another Delphi 6 application everything works fine.

However when I call the DLL from a C# application (compiled as 32bit app on 64bit machine), my c#  application simply crashes.

On debugging the DLL, I found that the first block of the above 3rd party code executes without any issue however the second block fails at second last line.

The error message is shown below:

```
System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
  Message="Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."
  Source="TestWinform"
  StackTrace:
       at TestWinform.TestSwitching()
       at TestWinform.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at TestWinform.Program.Main()
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

**EDIT:**

I have created a sample DLL project in Delphi 6 to replicate the problem.

Source code from *DelphiDllTest.dpr* file is given below:

```
library DelphiDllTest;
uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  MyUnit in 'MyUnit.pas';

{$R *.res}

procedure TestSwitching; export;
var
  myDict : TMyDictionary;
begin
  myDict := TMyDictionary.Create(nil);
  try        
    myDict.Open;
  finally
    myDict.Close;
    FreeAndNil(myDict);
  end;
end;

exports
TestSwitching;
begin
end.
```

Source of *MyUnit.pas* is given below:

```
    unit MyUnit;

    interface

    uses
      Classes, Windows;

    type

     TMyDictionary = class(TComponent)
      public
        constructor Create(owner: TComponent); override;
        destructor Destroy; override;
        procedure Open; virtual;
        procedure Close; virtual;
     end;

    function TranslateLoadResString(resStringRec: PResStringRec): String;
    function trLoadResString(resStringRec: PResStringRec): String;

    const
      SIZE_C = 32;

    var
      loadResStringBuffer: array[0..SIZE_C] of Byte;

    implementation

    constructor TMyDictionary.Create(owner: TComponent);
    begin
      inherited Create(owner);
    end;

    destructor TMyDictionary.Destroy;
    begin
      inherited Destroy;
    end;

    procedure TMyDictionary.Open;
    var
      protect: Integer;
    begin
      VirtualProtect(@LoadResString, SIZE_C, PAGE_READWRITE, @protect);
      Move((@LoadResString)^, loadResStringBuffer, SIZE_C);
      Move((@trLoadResString)^, (@LoadResString)^, SIZE_C);
      VirtualProtect(@LoadResString, SIZE_C, protect, @protect);
      FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess, @LoadResString, SIZE_C);
    end;

    procedure TMyDictionary.Close;
    var
      protect: Integer;
    begin
        VirtualProtect(@LoadResString, SIZE_C, PAGE_READWRITE, @protect);
        Move(loadResStringBuffer, (@LoadResString)^, SIZE_C);
        VirtualProtect(@LoadResString, SIZE_C, protect, @protect);
    end;


    function TranslateLoadResString(resStringRec: PResStringRec): String;
    var
      buffer: array[0..1023] of Char;
    begin
      try
        if resStringRec <> nil then
        begin
          if resStringRec.Identifier < 64*1024 then
          begin
            SetString(
              Result,
              buffer,
              LoadString(
                FindResourceHInstance(resStringRec.Module^),
                resStringRec.Identifier,
                buffer,
                SizeOf(buffer)));
          end
          else
            Result := PChar(resStringRec.Identifier);
        end
        else
          Result := '';

      except
        Result := '';
      end;
    end;

    function trLoadResString(resStringRec: PResStringRec): String;
    asm
      PUSH  EBP
      MOV   EBP, ESP
      ADD   ESP, $-8
      MOV   [EBP-$8], EDX
      MOV   [EBP-$4], EAX
      MOV   EDX, [EBP-$8]
      MOV   EAX, [EBP-$4]
      MOV   ECX, OFFSET Addr(TranslateLoadResString)-$1
      CALL  ECX
      MOV   ESP,EBP
      POP   EBP
    end;

    end.
```

Now finally the C# code which uses that DLL is given below:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestWinform
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("DelphiDllTest.dll")]
        public static extern void TestSwitching();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TestSwitching();            
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this is enough to generate the AV.

Comment: It's quite plausible that your interop is to blame. We cannot see it. An MCVE would be useful, as always.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : So you think it has something to do with the function exporting from within the Delphi DLL? What do you mean by "MCVE"?

Comment: Well, we don't know whether or not you messed up the interop. Quite plausible that you did. You can use a search engine to answer the other question.

Comment: @David means [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoveflow.com/help/mcve.exe), which is a long way of saying *provide the minimal code necessary to compile and execute in order to allow us to reproduce this issue so we can debug it*. Without code that will actually reproduce the problem that we can use, it's pretty difficult to help you diagnose the problem. I'm suspecting it's either a calling convention related issue or an issue with some structure alignment, but without more code I couldn't say for sure. It could be a simple usage issue as well.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : Sorry I could not provide the complete source code to reproduce the issue earlier as it was the 3rd party code. However, I have managed to replicate the problem in a test application. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Thanks. Can't look at it right now. Calling convention mismatch, benign since there are no params. Try/Finally is messed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that DEP is responsible for the exceptions. The problem is with the protection option that you are using. Instead of `PAGE_READWRITE` you need to use `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE`. In `Open`, you need to protect `@trLoadResString` as well as `@LoadResString`, you are missing that call to `VirtualProtect`.

Perhaps like this:

```
VirtualProtect(@LoadResString, SIZE_C, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, @protect);
Move((@LoadResString)^, loadResStringBuffer, SIZE_C);
VirtualProtect(@LoadResString, SIZE_C, protect, @protect);
FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess, @LoadResString, SIZE_C);

VirtualProtect(@trLoadResString, SIZE_C, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, @protect);
Move((@trLoadResString)^, (@LoadResString)^, SIZE_C);
VirtualProtect(@trLoadResString, SIZE_C, protect, @protect);
FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess, @trLoadResString, SIZE_C);
```

And you need to do something similar in the `Close` method. Perhaps you need to restore `trLoadResString`.

Your exported function is using the `register` calling convention, but it should export as `stdcall`. The `export` directive is ignored. It's only `exports` that matters.

Comment: I totally agree with you. It does seem something related to DEP. The application was working fine on WinXP but not on Win7. Using the `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` flag solved the problem. I've  also protected the `@trLoadResString` now.